# Running webpack bundle without a server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mobile, webpack

I have a project (angularjs) that is using webpack for bundling and it is deployed to a "release" directory with the webpack configuration output.publicPath set to "/".

If I grab the contents of my "release" directory (webpack bundle, index.html, and assets) and place them in a server (apache, iis or nodejs/express) directory it works great.

A problem occurs and I get a WHITE PAGE in the following three scenarios:

- If I try to just open the index.html page from the "release"
  directory in a browser (no server) with output.publicPath set to "/"
  or set to a url (http://www.example.com/) in the webpack config
- If I place it inside a mobile container such as cordova with
  output.publicPath set to "/" or set to a url in the webpack config
- If I change my output.publicPath from "/" to a url

My questions:

Why is webpack working fine with output.publicPath set to "/" and not set to a url (http://www.example.com/) in the webpack config?

To run a webpack bundled web application, do I need to have a server (apache, iis) running or can I just click on the index.html to view the app in a browser or just place it in a mobile container such as cordova?

Seems to me that my webpack bundled web application will only work with output.publicPath set to "/" and also needs a server to run.

I have tried many setups and only the first one at the beginning of this post works for browser not mobile.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the script tag you're using to pull in the bundled JavaScript as well as your folder structure? Additionally, can you open dev tools in your browser and list any console errors?

Comment: I have formatted/edited  my question  to better indicate my issue... also I am using angular which i think it adds a little bit of complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is webpack compatible with mobile platform containers such as cordova or do I need to do something special for it to work?

yes, you can use webpack with cordova without problems. You can check this repo https://github.com/uhlryk/my-cordova-react-boilerplate (it is my repo but in github there is many other examples of webpack bundle for cordova)

> To run a webpack bundle application, do I have to have a server (apache, iis) or can I just click on the index.html to view the app?

It depends on what you have there in details. But it is possible to click index.html and run app. Check my other repo https://github.com/uhlryk/react-dynamic-number and look on example - http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/uhlryk/react-dynamic-number/blob/master/example/index.html You can just click example/index.html and react app (webpack bundle) works.

Comment: I have formatted/edited  my question  to better indicate my issue... also I am using angular which i think it adds a little bit of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when just opening index.html without a server. The reason for me was that it was looking for the dependencies in the wrong place (dev tools console error):
[image: Error in dev tools console]

I used this generator to create my app: https://github.com/shibbir/generator-angular2-typescript

Clearly it looks for the file at a "root" (/) location, and that fails when you open from the file system (unless the files are in your root folder).